# Use Vue computed property in more than one place but only calculate once

Tags: vue.js

How can I use a Vue computed property in more than once place but only make the computed property function run only once and not once for every single time that I use it?

I am using the computed function output in 4 places, this makes the function call to the computed property run 4 times!

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are actually cached in Vue as [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) says:

> computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A
> computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive
> dependencies have changed.

Maybe we can figure out what is the problem if you provide a code sample

Comment: I checked my code and realised that the computed value is a global mixin. This means that effectively the computed value is a fresh copy available to each component and therefore although it seems that it is running 4 times it is actual 4 separate versions of the computed function  running. Am I understanding this right.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Found this github issue
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6712

Comment: Not sure what i thought I was doing. Will just move it to VUEX. that should sort the problem with a getter.